# keycloack-js client just returns "undefined" when checking for authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak

I am initializing keycloakClient in my SPA (react / typescript), and I do not find what I am doing wrong. When I click on then
Login button I get to the app page in keycloak and after successful authentication I see the network traffic pointing me to "/internal".
However, inside Router.tsx, I always get that `keycloakClient.authenticated` is *undefined*, and thus I am redirected to "/login". Seems that the instance of keycloakClient gets lost, and then every time starts from scratch?

In my app.tsx, I wrap everything with my provider:

```js
import { keycloakClient } from './components/KeycloakProvider/keycloakClient';
const App = () => {
    return (
        <KeycloakProvider client={keycloakClient}>
            <Router />
        </KeycloakProvider>
    );
};
```

inside Router.tsx, I protect some of the pages with it:

```js
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const { keycloakClient } = useKeycloak();
    console.log(keycloakClient.authenticated);
    if (!keycloakClient.authenticated) return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;

    return children;
};
const Router = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route
                path="/internal"
                element={
                    <PrivateRoute>
                        <Internal />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                }
            />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

in Login.tsx, I have a button to request authentication. When clicked upon, this gets executed:

```js
const doLogin = async (keycloakClient: Keycloak) => {
    await keycloakClient.init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/internal`,
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        pkceMethod: 'S256'
    });
};
```

And, with respect to the the provider, this is keycloakClient.tsx

```js
import Keycloak, { KeycloakConfig } from 'keycloak-js';

const keycloakConfig: KeycloakConfig = await fetch('/api/auth/props')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        return {
            url: data.auth_server_url,
            realm: data.realm,
            clientId: data.client_name
        };
    });

export const keycloakClient = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
```

this is the implementation of keycloakContext.tsx:

```js
const KeycloakContext = createContext<IKeycloakContextData | undefined>(undefined);
export default KeycloakContext;
```

this is the implementation for keycloakProvider.tsx:

```js
export const KeycloakProvider: React.FC<KeycloakProviderProps> = ({ client, children }) => {
    const contextValue: IKeycloakContextData = {
        keycloakClient: client
    };

    return <KeycloakContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</KeycloakContext.Provider>;
};
```

and, finally, this is the one for useKeycloak.tsx:

```js
export const useKeycloak = (): IKeycloakContextData => {
    const context = useContext(KeycloakContext);

    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useKeycloak must be used within a KeycloakProvider');
    }

    return context;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the autorization code flow, that requires a redirection from the server, thus reloading the page (which SPA pages do not like). At the end, what I did was to store the couple of parameters needed to rebuild the state in the session stored. Then, when the second time the page gets loaded, because those details are in place the workflow gets properly managed and all works.